# What is the correct way to have a neverending loop running on a separate thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating an application that's going to be continuously listening out for incoming signals via TCP until it's either stopped via a button, or the application closes. Being as the PC that the application is running on needs to run quite CPU-heavy stuff, I figured I should run this in a separate thread so that it doesn't hog the CPU.

My thoughts are to use a `BackgroundWorker` containing an inner-loop in `DoWork()` that checks the `IsCancellationPending` flag (this is set via the `CancelAsync()` method when the user clicks the stop button or exits the application). Is this the best route to go, or is there some other method that's more accepted?

Comment: Listening for TCP connections should *not* "hog the CPU". Do such might *block* the current thread .. but there is a bit of a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing an IO bound operation, so you shouldn't even be using another thread *at all*.  You should be handling the work asynchronously, in which an event, callback, Task, etc. fires to indicate that you have a message to process, which you can process and then go back to *not using any thread at all*.

Creating a thread that's just going to spend the vast majority of its time sitting there doing nothing while you wait for network activity isn't a productive use of resources.

Comment: Thankyou @Servy! In that case, should I use 'await' and 'async'?

Comment: @Lee.J.Baxter You certainly can, if you want to.

Comment: The last sentence is silly. A thread "doing nothing [but waiting on IO]" is not wasting any resources per se; and definitely no more than using `async`-enabled IO calls. It is when a thread spins its wheels in a loop and/or performs work unnecessarily that is a waste of system resources .. but such is not an intrinsic property of being a thread.

Comment: @user2864740 It's absolutely wasting resources.  You're spending time spinning it up, it's using a pretty fair bit of memory for the thread, etc.  There are also generally limits on the number of concurrent threads a process can have, so creating a lot of threads, even if they're all sleeping, can rather easily put you in a position where you can't create new ones when you need them, etc.  They're certainly not just free.  Using threads for this also gets very expensive very quick if you start creating and discarding threads regularly.